# Code works in terminal but not in script for renaming (manipulate filenames with spaces)

Tags: command-line, scripts, rename

I want to learn more so I have tried to script more than just using the terminal. I know `rename` and I can rename image files with `rename 's/ /_/g' *.jpg` but when I write it in a shell script to point at a directory:

```
DIRECTORY="/foo/bar"

for imgfile in $(find $DIRECTORY -type f -name \*.jpg); do
    echo 'replacing whitespace in' $(basename $imgfile)
    rename -f 's/ /_/g' *.jpg 
done
```

it doesn't work and the terminal will take a file (example: `1234 abcd.jpg`) and echo `abcd.jpg`.  So where am I going wrong?

Comment: this doesnt add up... you are looping the result from find and renaming all jpg in that dir on every iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaces in filenames are evil.

I see three problems with the script:

1. when doing the `for...` loop, you will have two different values when you find a file with space. i.e., if you have the files `"file1 1.jpg"` and `"file2 2.jpg"` and you do:

   ```
   for i in $(find . -type f -name \*.jpg); do 
      echo $i
   done
   ```

   You'll have

   ```
   ./file1 
   1.jpg
   ./file2
   2.jpg
   ```

   because the shell breaks the argument at spaces. The output of the `$(find ...)` command will be

   ```
   ./file1 1.jpg 
   ./file2 2.jpg
   ```

   Which are four words for the command `for` to be assigned at `$i` --- by default the shell treats spaces and newlines in the same way when expanding.

   You can circumvent this [changing the IFS char](https://superuser.com/questions/409818/how-do-i-parse-the-output-of-the-find-command-when-filenames-have-spaces-in-them).

   Your first line could look like:

   ```
   IFS=$'\n' find $DIRECTORY -type f -name \*.jpg | while read -r imgfile; do
   ```
2. you are feeding the for loop with a single file name, so you should say:

   ```
   rename -f 's/ /_/g' "$imgfile"
   ```

   otherwise `*.jpg` is expanded in the current directory, and not in `$DIRECTORY` (and note the quotes --- given that `$imgfile` is going to have spaces in it).
3. even then, if `$DIRECTORY` has some path component with spaces in it, the rename  will fail (there will be intermediate directories that do not exist).
4. suggestion (keeping it simple):

   ```
   DIRECTORY="/foo/bar"
   cd $DIRECTORY
   rename -f 's/ /_/g' *.jpg
   ```

   doesn't do what you want?

**Added**: my script (created ages ago, when there was no `rename` in Unix), is this --- it will remove spaces and tab in all files in current dir that have them in the name:

```
# 
ls -1  | grep -E " |\t" | while read i; do
    a=`echo $i | tr " \t" "__"`
    mv -v "$i" $a
done
```

**Added++**: [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls?highlight=%28%28BashPitfalls%29%29) I found researching this answer is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to parse the result from `find` is by null terminate the output with `-print0`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -d '' -r; do
    rename -f "s/ /_/g" "$REPLY"
    if [[ ! -f $REPLY ]]; then
        echo "Renaming file: $(basename "$REPLY")"
    fi
done < <(find -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0)
```

(You can manage without a loop).

```bsh
$ find -type f -name '*.jpg' \
    -exec bash -c 'rename -f "s/ /_/g" "$1"; \
    [[ -f $1 ]] || echo "Renaming file: $(basename "$1")"' _ '{}' \;
```